# JavaScript: при возникновении ошибки на странице - отправить код серверу через AJAX

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!

Есть ли на JavaScript такая возможность, чтобы  при возникновении ошибки на странице, отправлять информацию об этом(ошибка, которая пишется в консоле, номер строки) посредством Ajax на сервер?

На сервере я бы получил код ошибки и определил версию браузера, если бы таковые имелись.

Подскажите, возможно ли это?

Comment: `window.onerror` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
window.addEventListener('error', function (errorEvent) {
    console.log('Сработал сыщик ошибок: ', errorEvent.error);
    // Отправляете запрос на сервер, в errorEvent есть вся информация
    // об ошибке
})

a.b;
```

Answer (score 0):

Да есть такая возможность и еще `dashboard` - [Rollbar](https://rollbar.com/). Бесплатный тариф на 5000 событий в месяц (вполне для тестирования).